# Google Analytics V4 to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have been using Google Analytics version v4 in an Android mobile application for the past few years; I am planning to move to Firebase Analytics.

If I move to Firebase Analytics as is, will I loose all data which is present in Google Analytics.?

If not how do i get the all data which is present in Google Analytics to Firebase Analytics.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. Google Analytics for Firebase (GA4F) and Google Analytics (GA) are actually different platforms from each other.

As that said, you will not lose your data in the Google Analytics (GA) console. And, after integrating the Google Analytics for Firebase (GA4F) SDK in your app, the data will be uploaded to the Firebase server and it will be displayed in its console.